# How to find all nodes in a graph equidistant from a given set of nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory, graph-algorithm

If you have a simple undirected graph `G(V,E)` and `F` which is a subset of `V`. How can you find some node `v` such that the distance from every node in `F` to `v` is the same and the distances are minimized? And just return `None` if there is no `v`. I was told this can be done in `O(|V|+|E|)` complexity.

Assume all edges are of distance 1.

Can anyone explain how this can be done? A pseudo-code would also help.

Comment: I think it is important to know if the distances are non-negative or positive?

Comment: @Alexander +1. My previous solution was based on the assumption that all edges are of distance 1.

Comment: All edges are of distance 1.

Comment: I don't understand. Please could you give an example?

Comment: Do you need a node v such the *shortest* distance from F to v are equal or such that at least one *path* from each of F to v are equal?

Comment: F is a subset of nodes of V. We need a node v, such that the shortest distances from v to each node of F is the same.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is similar to BFS, but with a little change:

1. Start with S = F with F nodes marked.
2. Find |S| sets with distance 1 from each element in S (all these sets should contain unmarked nodes). If the intersection of these sets is non-empty, the candidate is found.
3. Take the union of the |S| sets above in S' and mark these nodes. If S' is empty, return 'None'.
4. Return to step 2.

Suppose all the set operations take constant time, then the complexity of the algorithm is same as BFS which is O(|V| + |E|).

Now to reason about the complexity of set operations. My reasoning is that the set operations don't increase the complexity as the union and intersection operations in steps 2 and 3 can be combined to take time O(|S|), and since at every step S is different from S in previous iterations, the overall complexity of set operations would be O(|V|).

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your algorithm, could you show a pseudo-code?

So to re-say what you said:
1. Set S = F, and then mark each node of S

2. Get the |S| sets of nodes that has a distance of 1 from each marked node of S.

3. If there is an intersect of all |S| sets, then that is the candidate.

4. Otherwise, we union the |S| sets, and repeat step 2.
Is this right?

Comment: Also I don't understand your reasoning, if there |S| operations, isn't it |S| times the complexity of BFS?

Comment: Yes, your summary is correct. As for |S| operations, the intersection of |S| sets can be done while those |S| sets are calculated by keeping two accumulators, one representing the union and other an intersection.

Comment: Are you sure this works?  If I'm reading this correctly, you would only find a node that's two hops away from every node in the set if that node was one hop away from *every single* node that was one hop away from the original set.  A node could be two hops away from each node in the original set if it's one hop away from just a single node that in turn is one hop away from each of the original nodes.

Comment: "A node could be two hops away from each node in the original set if it's one hop away from just a single node that in turn is one hop away from each of the original nodes." If the one hop node is found, the algorithm returns that as candidate in step 2 so the case mentioned above would never arise. I agree that if "all" equidistant nodes are to be found the above solution won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one algorithm, in pseudo-code, trying to add comments to explain how it works.

```
declare explored // a table of all the vertices that can keep track of one number (distance, initialized to -1) and a list of vertex references (origins, initialized to null)
to_explore = S  // fifo queue of vertices to explore

while (to_explore not empty) {
    pop vertex v from to_explore
    current_distance = explored[v].distance
    current_origins = explored[v].origins
    for (vertex n, neighbor of v) {
        if (explored[n].origins contains v)
            continue // we just hit a loop and we're only interested in shortest distances
        if (explored[n].distance == -1) { // first time we come here
            explored[n].distance = current_distance+1
            explored[n].origins = current_origins
            push n to to_explore
            continue
        }
        if (explored[n].distance != current_distance+1) {
            continue // we are merging path from another node of S but different distance, cannot lead to any solution
        }
        // only case left is explored[n].distance == current_distance+1
        // so we've already come here from other place(s) in S with the same distance
        add / merge (without duplicates) origins to explored[n].origins
        if (explored[n].origins = S) // maybe compare the size is enough?
            return n // we found a solution
        // if not , we just continue our exploration, no need to add to the queue since we've already been through here before
    }
}
```

The idea is that with the FIFO queue, we will explore everything that's at distance 1 from the set S, if we cannot find any solution there, everything at distance 2...etc.. so we'll find the shortest distance first.

I am not completely sure about the complexity, but I believe that in the worst case, we only explore every vertex and every edge only once so that would give `O(|E| + |V|)`. But in some case we visit the same vertex multiple times. Although that does not increase the paths to explore much, I am not sure if there should be a factor |S| somewhere (but if that is just considered like a constant, then it's ok...)

Hope I did not miss anything. Obviously I did not test any of this.... :)

**EDIT** (reply to comment)

> Will your code work for a graph like this? E = ( a, b), (a, c), (a,d)
>   , (b,e), (c,e), (d, e), and my F = { b, c , d}. Say, you start your
>   bfs with a. I suspect, in the end the origins array will only have {a}
>   and therefore the code will return None. – Guru Devanla

In this case, here is what happens:

```
to_explore is initialized to {b,c,d}
//while (to_explore not empty)
pop one from to_explore (b). to_explore becomes {c,d}
current_distance=0
current_origins={b}
//for (neighbors of b) {
handling 'a' as neighbor of b first
explored[a].distance=1
explored[a].origins={b}
to_explore becomes {c,d,a}
//for (neighbors of b)
handling 'e' as next neighbor of b
explored[e].distance=1
explored[e].origins={b}
to_explore becomes {c,d,a,e}
//while (to_explore not empty)
pop one from to_explore (c). to_explore becomes {d,a,e}
current_distance=0
current_origins={c}
//for (neighbors of c)
handling 'a' as neighbor of c first
explored[a].distance is already 1
explored[a].origins={b,c}
to_explore already contains a
//for (neighbors of c) {
handling 'e' as next neighbor of b
explored[e].distance is already 1
explored[e].origins={b,}
to_explore already contains e
//while (to_explore not empty)
pop one from to_explore (d)
current_distance=0
current_origins={d}
//for (neighbors of d)
handling 'a' as neighbor of d first
explored[a].distance is already 1
explored[a].origins={b,c,d}
that matches F, found a as a solution.
```

Comment: Will your code work for a graph like this?  E = ( a, b), (a, c), (a,d) , (b,e), (c,e), (d, e), and my F = { b, c , d}. Say, you start your bfs with a. I suspect, in the end the origins array will only have {a} and therefore the code will return None.

Comment: @GuruDevanla, I edited the answer to explain what happens in this case. I believe that would work just fine in this case...

Comment: glad to see it worked for all cases i tried to prove the algo wrong ! .